# How to be sure that setValue to firebase child worked successfully?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `addOnCompleteListener`, but I need to setValue to more than one child at time, it will not be good if I check if 1st child updated then update the 2nd then the 3rd ... etc, it will be very complicated

Also I need to test `addOnFailureListener, addOnCanceledListener` ,and when they will be triggered and what the best action should be taken in these case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

`public Task<Void> setValue (Object value)`

> Set the data at this location to the given value. Passing null to setValue() will delete the data at the specified location. The native types accepted by this method for the value correspond to the JSON types:
>
> Boolean
>
> Long
>
> Double
>
> String
>
> Map
>
> List

Therefore if you have multiple `setValue()`, you can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("name","peter");
values.put("age","100");
ref.setValue(values).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            System.out.println("completed");
        }
    });
```

Of you can use a pojo class instead of map.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)

Comment: thank you for sharing this answer for the 1st question, please if you can help in other 2 questions .

Comment: @Tarek the addoncompletelistener returns a Task, therefore you can call addoncanceledlistener and onfailurelistener also.. regarding the third question if the users are changing the same value then you need to use https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions other than that no you don't have to do anything

Comment: addOnFailureListener, addOnCanceledListener ,and when they will be triggered and what the best action should be taken in these case ?

3rd Q: means if there are 1000 user chatting for example using my app, is it guaranteed that it will be successful operation, and the server can handle all pushed values ?

Comment: `oncanceled` Adds a listener that is called if the Task is canceled. `addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener listener)`
Adds a listener that is called if the Task fails. Yes it can handle https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html

Comment: my db structure is not simple as the answer, there nested childs as```values.put("name","peter"); ``` peter has childs reference, each child has childs also ..